# how do i add 3 salaries using array index?

Tags: java

I need help getting total amount for salary using `printf` statement
numbers/salary i need to add to get total salary;

```
salary 1: 120000.00 
salary 2: 200500.00 
salary 3: 175000.50 total 
payroll amount is $495501.49
```

I need help getting total and the code to get the total payroll amount
This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class LabSeven {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] playerName = new String[3];
        Double []dollarSalary= new Double[3];
        double sum= 0;

        for(int i=0; i<3 ; i++){
            System.out.print("Enter player name: ");
            playerName[i]=input.next();
            System.out.print("Enter Salary: ");
            dollarSalary[i]=input.nextDouble();
        }

        double total= sum + dollarSalary;
        System.out.printf("Total payroll amount is: %7.2f\n", sum);

        for(int i=0; i<=3; i++) {
            System.out.printf(" %s %7.2f\n", playerName[i], dollarSalary[i]);
        }
        input.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: i got it thanks for your help

Comment: now i need help with this other problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700251/how-would-i-program-this-correctly

Comment: if my answer answered your question, then please mark it accepted

Answer (score 2):

After this line:

> ```
> dollarSalary[i]=input.nextDouble();
> ```

Add this line:

```
sum += dollarSalary[i];
```

This way you will be accumulating the sum in the `sum` variable.

And, delete this line, as you cannot add an array to a double value, this statement made no sense:

> ```
> double total= sum + dollarSalary;
> ```

Finally, you have one more bug, here:

> ```
> for(int i=0; i<=3; i++) {
> ```

The problem is that `i` will take values 0, 1, 2, 3, but the size of the arrays is 3, so the only valid values are 0, 1, 2. Change the condition to `<` instead of `<=`:

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
```

#### Extra tips

- Don't use a `Double[]`. A `double[]` is enough for your purpose here
- Don't write the number 3 repeatedly. Define a constant, for example `private static final PLAYERS_NUM`and use this everywhere instead. That way if you want to change the number of players later, you can do it in one place instead of 4
- Format your code nicely. Use an IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse, and use their auto-format features

#### Putting it together

With the above suggestions applied, your program becomes:

```
public class LabSeven {
    private static final int PLAYERS_NUM = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] playerName = new String[PLAYERS_NUM];
        double[] dollarSalary = new double[PLAYERS_NUM];

        double totalSalary = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < PLAYERS_NUM; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter player name: ");
            playerName[i] = input.next();
            System.out.print("Enter Salary: ");
            double salary = input.nextDouble();
            dollarSalary[i] = salary;
            totalSalary += salary;
        }

        System.out.printf("Total payroll amount is: %7.2f\n", totalSalary);

        for (int i = 0; i < PLAYERS_NUM; i++) {
            System.out.printf(" %s %7.2f\n", playerName[i], dollarSalary[i]);
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this line in your for-loop and remove your `total` variable you don't need this.

```
sum += input.nextDouble();
```

or

```
sum += dollarSalary[i];
```

You can't add an array to a variable like you're doing.

Comment: I think OP is storing salary for each player

Comment: He's adding `input.nextDouble()` to `dollarSalary`. Each index is the salary of a player.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this to add the salaries from your array. In your `for` after you add an individual salary to your `dollarSalary` add it to your `sum` variable as well.

```
for(int i=0; i<3 ; i++){
    System.out.print("Enter player name: ");
    playerName[i]=input.next();
    System.out.print("Enter Salary: ");
    dollarSalary[i]=input.nextDouble();
    sum += dollarSalary[i]
    //sum += input.nextDouble(); This expects another input from the user. We should not be doing this. 
}
//double total= sum + dollarSalary;  You dont need this line anymore
System.out.printf("Total payroll amount is: %7.2f\n", sum);
```

Comment: Do not uses float or double for monetary computations - roundoff/truncation errors will cause great headaches. Use int instead and have your units in cents, not dollars.

Comment: @FredK Was using the data types that OP uses in the original code. Was only answering the question of how to add elements from an Array. But I do agree, thanks for the input FredK.