# How would i program this correctly?

Tags: java

what the program wants me to code:

> Code an executable program that will produce
>   an invoice for a customer ordering a number
>   of products at a store. A sample run of the
>   program is shown to the right.
>
> Your program
>   must ask for the number of products (up to a
>   maximum of 12 products may be ordered) and
>   then successively ask for the product name and
>   its cost. The invoice produced includes:
>
>  the title of the store (as shown),
>    product names and their cost,
>    calculated cost of all products,
>    calculated 5% sales tax,
>    overall total cost
>    a thank you.
>
> The products and their cost must be kept in
>   parallel arrays. Two methods must be coded.
>   One method will display the title. The second
>   method will accept the calculated cost of all
>   products and return the calculated sales tax.
>   The method that computes the sales tax must
>   use a named constant for the 5% tax rate.

picture of example run of what it should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAgzI.jpg

Currently my program is this so far, but im not sure if it is correct or if i need to make the variables into an array.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        int product;
        String products;
        double cost;

        System.out.println("How many products? ");
        product=input.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < product; i++){

            System.out.println("Product Name: ");
            products=input.next();

            System.out.println("Cost: ");
            cost=input.nextDouble();
        }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can fill your array:

```
double[] costArray = new double[product]; 
for(int i = 0; i < product; i++){
    costArray[i] = input.nextDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an array for variables **products** and **cost** like this:

```
 static final float TAXES = 0.05f;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    double tax;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int product;
    String products[];
    double cost[];

    System.out.println("How many products? ");
    product = input.nextInt();
    products = new String[product];
    cost = new double[product];

    for (int i = 0; i < product; i++) {

        System.out.println("Product Name: ");
        products[i] = input.next();

        System.out.println("Cost: ");
        cost[i] = Double.parseDouble(input.next().trim().replace(',', '.'));
    }

    indentedText();

    for (int i = 0; i < product; i++) {
        System.out.printf(products[i] + '\t' + "%.2f %n", cost[i]);
        sum = sum + cost[i];
    }
    tax = calculateTaxes(sum);
    System.out.printf("Sub total:" + '\t' + "%.2f %n", sum);
    System.out.printf("Sales tax:" + '\t' + "%.2f %n", tax);
    System.out.printf("Total to be paid:" + '\t' + "%.2f %n %n", (sum + tax));
    System.out.print('\t' + "Thank you!");

}

private static void indentedText() {
    System.out.print('\t' + "The Company Store" + '\n' + '\n');

}

private static double calculateTaxes(double sum) {
    return sum * TAXES;
}
```

Comment: how would i do this part?  the title of the store (as shown),  product names and their cost,  calculated cost of all products,  calculated 5% sales tax,  overall total cost  a thank you.

The products and their cost must be kept in parallel arrays. Two methods must be coded. One method will display the title. The second method will accept the calculated cost of all products and return the calculated sales tax. The method that computes the sales tax must use a named constant for the 5% tax rate.

Comment: @Java I have already edited my last post with the solution to your problem.